# Updating point color with data grouping

Tags: highcharts

Updating point color when the data is not initially grouped works, as can be seen here:

http://jsfiddle.net/ppekcr2c/3/

While updating point color when the data is initially grouped does not appear to work, as can be seen by clicking on the "30m" button here:

http://jsfiddle.net/ppekcr2c/4/

The only difference between the two code excerpts is the initially selected range. In the first case it is:

```
    selected: 0,
```

and in the second case:

```
    selected: 1,
```

Is there a way point color can be changed even though data grouping occurs with the initially selected range?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with `series.data`, which can be empty once `dataGrouping` is used.

Workaround can be to use `series.points` instead, just like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ppekcr2c/6/

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. `series.points` does not appear to be part of the official API, though.